# Cannot find "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash

I got problems with installing "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows". I've used [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) tutorial to help me process through installation steps. I'd like to note that this tutorial worked for me without any problems on other device, however for some reason on my laptop I can't get it done.

I've got stuck at step where after "Bash" installation I simply cannot locate the icon or "run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" anywhere on my computer. However I was able to find the folder, where Linux environment was installed. I couldn't find a "run shell" inside this folder though, which confuses me.

For a better understanding of my problem I will attach the pictures.

[image: Bash installation success on Windows PowerShell]

[image: Cannot find using keyword Ubuntu]

[image: Linux environment folder found in Windows, but no "Run Shell app" inside it]

Comment: 2. Cannot find "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" by keyword "Ubuntu" or "bash" http://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ9e8.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/QRFX3.png

3. Linux environment folder found in Windows, but no "Run Shell app" inside it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/al3H2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you launched the `bash` command, then **you are inside the Linux Shell already!**

Nothing more to do. As you can observe, the *prompt* changed to

```
xeho91@ANAQUEM:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$
```

Welcome aboard!

Comment: Yes, I know. However it doesn't show up as "Bash Ubuntu on Windows" and neither there is any separate icon / run shell for it. I can rush Linux Shell only via cmd or PowerShell. This is confusing for me.

Comment: Then you could create a shortcut yourself that would call it for you? What happens when you hit the `windows` key, then call bash directly?

Comment: I haven't thought of this solution yet! Thank you J. Chomel! :)

Comment: @xeho91 I encountered exactly the same problem. According to the tutorial, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/  there should be "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10", and its looking and font are linux style. However, the bash I own now is windows cmd style. What on earth am I missing?